# Solve Exponential equation $2^x=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve this exponential equation:

$$2^x=3$$

To do this, I apply the logarithm of base 2 to both sides of the equation:

$$\log_22^x = 3 \implies x\log_22 = \log_23 \implies x = \log_23$$

I would not be able to go on from here. My textbook suggests that the answer is $\frac 1 9$. How? I can't really wrap my head around this even though I know this is pretty easy. Any hints?

Edit: this is what the textbook adds:

$$\log_3x = -2$$

And then applies a function $3^t$ so that

$$x=3^{-2}= \frac 1 9$$

Comment: You are right and text book is wrong.

Comment: You've gone as far as you can easily go.  Analytic methods show that $\log_23\approx 1.584962501$.  Certainly not $\frac 19$  (easy to see that, in fact, it is irrational).

Comment: Your answer is right and $1/9$ is wrong. The correct numerical value is about $1.58$. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: change book! :P

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I have added what the textbook is doing to my question

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: The book is called PreCalculus by Marco Bramanti https://books.google.it/books?id=xNsOBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=Sono+quelle+equazioni+o+disequazioni+che+coinvolgono+l%27incognita+attraverso+una+sua+funzione+esponenziale+o+logaritmica+e+che+quindi+per+essere+risolte+richiedono,+in+qualche+passagio,+di+applicare+ad+ambo+i+membri+una+funzione+esponenziale+(per+liberare+dal+logaritmo+l%27incognita)&source=bl&ots=Y6bpQmW609&sig=rxRpyLGfp_VXwmsZZG1dpMzu0Qs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjswveftb_cAhUCExoKHSjiBzoQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ

Comment: $3^{-2} = \frac 19$ and $\log_3 \frac 19 = -2$ but that has little to do with $\log_2 3  \approx 1.58$ and $2^{1.58} \approx 3$

Comment: Ops, it seems that the book reports *two distinct examples* of logarithmic and exponential equations but it's not made clear from the text. Sorry and thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your solution is absolutely correct, indeed by definition

$$2^x=2^{(\log_2 3)}=3$$

That seems the solution to

$$\log_3 x=-2 \implies 3^{\log_3 x}=3^{-2} \implies x=\frac19 $$